# Google FusedProvider does not call onLocationChanged() in an environment without GPS

Tags: android, gps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

My app works fine if the area has GPS (such as outside) or in houses/first or second floor buildings but it does not receive a location update if the area is something like the 4th-10th floor of a tall building, is this expected behavior or is this a limitation of location services?

Even with an internet connection on a high floor it still does not receive an update, this makes me believe that it is not falling back to Wi-Fi/mobile networks but I tried setting my Location method to Wi-Fi/Mobile only in the Android settings but it still works in normal environments.

Can anyone give me advice on what is happening? Do location services simply not work at higher altitudes or certain areas with very poor reception? I have not tested it in underground parking areas though.

I am using PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY as my priority.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY as my priority.

That's the reason you are not getting Location change inside a building. Because HIGH_ACCURACY gets location from **GPS** provider. As we know GPS doesn't work well inside houses as it collects location from satellite.

You can try out other options.

- PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY (About 100 meter)
- PRIORITY_LOW_POWER (About 10km)
- PRIORITY_NO_POWER (Act as a passive listener )

You may visit [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) if you havn't yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the FusedProvider not dynamically fall back to wi-fi/mobile networks if GPS isnt avaliable? Where did you learn that it only uses GPS?